# Problems installing x2goserver-xsession on a fresh install of CentOS 7.1 on Amazon EC2

Tags: linux, installation, centos

I have a fresh install of CentOS 7.1 on Amazon EC2. After boot I executed:

```
yum update
```

Then I enabled an EPEL with:

```
rpm -Uvh https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/e/epel-release-7-5.noarch.rpm
```

Fine. After that I tried to install [`x2go`](http://wiki.x2go.org/doku.php) with the command line below:

```
yum -y install x2goserver-xsession
```

I get many many lines and at the bottom it says this:

```
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: x2goserver-4.0.1.19-3.el7.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: perl(File::Which)
Error: Package: x2goserver-4.0.1.19-3.el7.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: perl(Config::Simple)
Error: Package: x2goserver-4.0.1.19-3.el7.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: perl(Capture::Tiny)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

What is really strange is that this same procedure work completely fine at Linode with a fresh install of CentOS 7.0. Why is Amazon EC2 having trouble to install x2go? Any idea how I can fix this?

Comment: yes, in my Linode I have CentOS 7 and at Amazon I have CENTOS 7.1. So how do I install this x2go on Amazon? Is there any plugin that I should "yum install" to fix this dependency issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, this has 100% nothing to do with Amazon EC2 servers versus Linode servers. This is a simple—but still complex—issue of am RPM needing dependencies that are not installed on the system. Clear up those dependencies and all should be good.

Before anything else, look at the errors returned:

```
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: x2goserver-4.0.1.19-3.el7.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: perl(File::Which)
Error: Package: x2goserver-4.0.1.19-3.el7.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: perl(Config::Simple)
Error: Package: x2goserver-4.0.1.19-3.el7.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: perl(Capture::Tiny)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

The issue is you just need to install `Requires: perl(File::Which)`, `Requires: perl(Config::Simple)` and `Requires: perl(Capture::Tiny)` before the main command. Those are [Perl CPAN modules](http://www.cpan.org). Apparently the RPM doesn’t handle those Perl specific dependencies.

While I’m unfamiliar with [`x2go`](http://wiki.x2go.org/doku.php), this should work for installing the Perl CPAN modules.

First, get into your home directory on the server:

```
cd ~/
```

Next, install Perl on your system like this:

```
sudo yum install perl
```

Or you might need to run this command to get Perl and CPAN installed:

```
sudo yum install perl-SPAN
```

But after that is done, run [`cpan`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/cpan) like this via `sudo`:

```
sudo cpan
```

Now install YAML for the CPAN setup:

```
install YAML
```

Finally, install the actual CPAN modules like this:

```
install File::Which Config::Simple Capture::Tiny
```

When that’s done, exit:

```
quit
```

And now run that `yum` command again:

```
yum -y install x2goserver-xsession
```

Hopefully that all works. But if all of this doesn’t work—or if more errors come up—this could mean you need to explicitly use a CentOS 7.0 OS on the Amazon EC2 instance.

Comment: Tnks so much! I am having this error at the beginning of your tutorial: 
bash: cpan: command not found

Comment: I got it! :) Now I get this error right after yum install x2goserver-xsession ->  Failing package is: libNX_Xcomposite1-3.5.0.32-0.0x2go1.1.git20150704.734.main.el7.centos.x86_64
 GPG Keys are configured as: http://packages.x2go.org/pub.key

Comment: Yes, you are damm right!!!!!! I will move back to Centos 7! Your help was very nice and it almost worked, anyway I will come back to Centos 7! Thank you so much!