# Install of CPAN Perl module on RHEL 7 fails (Amazon EC2)

Tags: linux, perl, redhat-enterprise-linux, dependencies, cpan

I am trying to install x2goserver on my RHEL 7 server. I ran into dependency issues exactly like [the question here](https://superuser.com/questions/971811/problems-installing-x2goserver-xsession-on-a-fresh-install-of-centos-7-1-on-amaz), (I am not familiar with Perl or CPAN, I just want a functioning x2goserver) so when I tried installing the CPAN Perl modules [as described in the answer](https://superuser.com/a/971818) this time I ran into the following output:

```
$ sudo cpan
Terminal does not support AddHistory.

cpan shell -- CPAN exploration and modules installation (v1.9800)
Enter 'h' for help.

cpan[1]> install File::Which
Reading '/root/.cpan/Metadata'
  Database was generated on Thu, 14 Jul 2016 21:53:35 GMT
Fetching with HTTP::Tiny:
http://mirror.ox.ac.uk/sites/www.cpan.org/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz
Reading '/root/.cpan/sources/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz'
............................................................................DONE
Fetching with HTTP::Tiny:
http://mirror.ox.ac.uk/sites/www.cpan.org/modules/02packages.details.txt.gz
Reading '/root/.cpan/sources/modules/02packages.details.txt.gz'
  Database was generated on Fri, 15 Jul 2016 22:17:02 GMT
  HTTP::Date not available
.............
  New CPAN.pm version (v2.14) available.
  [Currently running version is v1.9800]
  You might want to try
    install CPAN
    reload cpan
  to both upgrade CPAN.pm and run the new version without leaving
  the current session.


...............................................................DONE
Fetching with HTTP::Tiny:
http://mirror.ox.ac.uk/sites/www.cpan.org/modules/03modlist.data.gz
Reading '/root/.cpan/sources/modules/03modlist.data.gz'
DONE
Writing /root/.cpan/Metadata
Running install for module 'File::Which'
Running make for P/PL/PLICEASE/File-Which-1.21.tar.gz
Checksum for /root/.cpan/sources/authors/id/P/PL/PLICEASE/File-Which-1.21.tar.gz ok
Scanning cache /root/.cpan/build for sizes
............................................................................DONE

  CPAN.pm: Building P/PL/PLICEASE/File-Which-1.21.tar.gz

Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Writing Makefile for File::Which
Could not read metadata file. Falling back to other methods to determine prerequisites
cp lib/File/Which.pm blib/lib/File/Which.pm
Manifying blib/man3/File::Which.3pm
  PLICEASE/File-Which-1.21.tar.gz
  /bin/make -- OK
Running make test
PERL_DL_NONLAZY=1 /usr/bin/perl "-MExtUtils::Command::MM" "-e" "test_harness(0, 'blib/lib', 'blib/arch')" t/*.t
t/00_diag.t ..... 1/1 # 
# 
# 
# HARNESS_ACTIVE=1
# HARNESS_VERSION=3.28
# LANG=en_US.UTF-8
# LC_ADDRESS=tr_TR.UTF-8
# LC_IDENTIFICATION=tr_TR.UTF-8
# LC_MEASUREMENT=tr_TR.UTF-8
# LC_MONETARY=tr_TR.UTF-8
# LC_NAME=tr_TR.UTF-8
# LC_NUMERIC=tr_TR.UTF-8
# LC_PAPER=tr_TR.UTF-8
# LC_TELEPHONE=tr_TR.UTF-8
# LC_TIME=tr_TR.UTF-8
# PERL5LIB=/root/.cpan/build/File-Which-1.21-lieZ00/blib/lib:/root/.cpan/build/File-Which-1.21-lieZ00/blib/arch:
# PERL5OPT=
# PERL5_CPANPLUS_IS_RUNNING=3630
# PERL5_CPAN_IS_RUNNING=3630
# PERL_DL_NONLAZY=1
# SHELL=/bin/bash
# 
# 
# 
# PERL5LIB path
# /root/.cpan/build/File-Which-1.21-lieZ00/blib/lib
# /root/.cpan/build/File-Which-1.21-lieZ00/blib/arch
# 
# 
# 
# perl                5.016003
# ExtUtils::MakeMaker 6.68
# Test::More          1.302040
# 
# 
# 
t/00_diag.t ..... ok   
t/01_compile.t .. ok   
t/02_all.t ...... Can't locate Env.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /root/.cpan/build/File-Which-1.21-lieZ00/blib/lib /root/.cpan/build/File-Which-1.21-lieZ00/blib/arch /usr/local/lib64/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5 /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 .) at t/02_all.t line 3.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at t/02_all.t line 3.
t/02_all.t ...... Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
No subtests run 
t/03_simple.t ... Can't locate Env.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /root/.cpan/build/File-Which-1.21-lieZ00/blib/lib /root/.cpan/build/File-Which-1.21-lieZ00/blib/arch /usr/local/lib64/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5 /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 .) at t/03_simple.t line 6.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at t/03_simple.t line 6.
# Looks like your test exited with 2 before it could output anything.
t/03_simple.t ... Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
Failed 10/10 subtests 
t/04_pwhich.t ... ok   

Test Summary Report
-------------------
t/02_all.t    (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
t/03_simple.t (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: Bad plan.  You planned 10 tests but ran 0.
Files=5, Tests=5,  0 wallclock secs ( 0.02 usr  0.01 sys +  0.17 cusr  0.01 csys =  0.21 CPU)
Result: FAIL
Failed 2/5 test programs. 0/5 subtests failed.
make: *** [test_dynamic] Error 255
  PLICEASE/File-Which-1.21.tar.gz
  /bin/make test -- NOT OK
//hint// to see the cpan-testers results for installing this module, try:
  reports PLICEASE/File-Which-1.21.tar.gz
Running make install
  make test had returned bad status, won't install without force
Failed during this command:
 PLICEASE/File-Which-1.21.tar.gz              : make_test NO
```

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange. For a question to be accepted on these sites, the OP **must** display some good will in detailing what has been tried, and what has failed, in trying to address a given question.  What do you make of the output? Have you searched thru Google for the error message you received? have you tried any of the solutions available online? If they failed, **how** did they fail?

Answer (score 1):

> » Can't locate Env.pm in @INC «

`File::Which` , and `Env` : # `yum install perl-File-Which perl-Env`

Please always use the search, like : `yum search file-which`

---

EDIT : About the other x2goserver dependencies :

```
# yum search perl-Config-Simple perl-Capture-Tiny
# yum install perl-Config-Simple perl-Capture-Tiny
```

Comment: Thank you, I was able to install File::Which with this but the main problem (unable to install x2goserver due to dependencies) continues.. Any ideas?

Comment: x2goserver dependencies : Please read my edited post.